# Why is there a deviation between the experimentally calculated values and theoretical done by DFT calculation?

Tags: density-functional-theory, condensed-matter, physical-properties-of-materials

If there was a deviation between the experimentally calculated values and theoretical determination done by DFT calculation, then what is the reason?

Comment: I would say this question is too broad. The answer clearly depends a lot on (1) whether the deviation is significantly larger than the typical error of that functional, and (2) which deviation you are talking about, e.g. do you mean a deviation of the formation energy, or a deviation of the band structure, or a deviation of the lattice constants?

Comment: The question can stay open if you take wzkchem5's advice, I've also adjusted the body to match the title.

Comment: Unless this question is heavily narrowed, I do not think it can remain open.  This is far too vague and potentially already answered in other questions.

Comment: There are several questions already dealing with issues in DFT, I know because I made one of them https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/526/181

Comment: I agree this is too broad. As a start, consider: 1) Is it a ground state property - i.e. would "the true" functional predict it correctly? 2) Is it a failure of our approximate functionals? 3) Do we need finite temperature simulations? 4) Is it a failure of practical DFT implementations, e.g. Born-Oppenheimer approximation? 5) Is the actual system modelled the same as the experimental one (e.g. are there defects in the experiment)? 6) Is it because we're pretending Kohn-Sham states are electronic/quasi-particle states, instead of actually using a constructed functional?

Comment: @PhilHasnip Some further possible considerations are 7) could it be user error (e.g. mistakes in inputs), and 8) was the experiment done and interpreted correctly?

Comment: @Anyon absolutely! Not to mention whether it was converged properly with respect to basis set size, Brillouin zone sampling etc. or whether any pseudopotentials had been tested properly... I think this question is impossible to answer without narrowing the scenario.

Comment: After being reminded of the question by @B.Kelly, I'm tempted to close this as a duplicate of that question. Usually I would want to give the OP more time to respond to comments and turn the advice people are giving into improvements to the question, but this question has already had comments from **six** different people, and to prevent disturbing other people's time, I'm voting to close this time. Ismail, you're always welcome to ask another question if you can make it **more detailed** and **more focused**, but please always search to see if it's been answered before!